# When we create AWS eks cluster ,where is master node which manages worker nodes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-eks, eksctl

I want to create a deployment , so need to have access to master node,so that I can login to  that node and create the deployment file.
But,when creating cluster with eksctl tool,only nodes are available.

Answer (score 3):

> so need to have access to master node,so that I can login to that node and create the deployment file

EKS is a managed service, so you have no direct access to the master nodes. And you don't need the access.

You can [authenticate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/managing-auth.html) and use the [configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-kubeconfig.html) with the default Kubernetes tools (e.g.  kubectl).